# How to move Primefaces-Upload-Temp-Files instead of doing a time intensive copy process?

Tags: java, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to upload files larger than 2 GB with Java EE with the use of primefaces. In general that it's not that big deal, but I have a little problem. The usually way with PrimeFaces is to upload a file, have that UploadedFile-Object, obtain the InputStream from that and then write it to disk.

But writing to disk large files is a time intensive task. Instead I would like to find the uploaded file in the file system and then move it to the folder, where I store all the files, because moving files is not wasting time.

So, according to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11829958/where-is-the-file-uploaded-using-primefaces-netbeans-in-local) I figured out to set PrimeFaces-Tmp-folder and the size-limit, when files will put there. Now every uploaded file just goes directly into that folder. The point is, that I now have a file on disk, while the user is uploading - and not creating it afterwards.

So far, so good. I could identify the file and just move it (although it has a strange name). But pointing to [Primefaces Userguide (Page 187)](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/indexed_primefaces_users_guide_3_5.pdf), this Tmp-Folder is just used internally. And I even would steal the contents of the UploadedFile-Object from Primefaces. Seems not to be a clean solution to me.

Any hints how to achieve this ?

I also saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931152/how-to-upload-files-without-turning-it-to-temporary-file-netbeans-jsf-primefac). Could also be my title, but it's not what I am looking for.

EDIT:

Because of the comment, some code. First I am collecting the UploadFile-Objects in the fileUploadListener:

```
   public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) throws IOException {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    getUploadedFilesDTO().add(new UploadedFileDTO(event.getFile(), uploadedFilesCounter));
    uploadedFilesCounter++;

}
```

Second in the EJB I am calling copyFile for every UploadedFile-Object:

```
private void copyFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile, String randomFilename) throws IOException {


    InputStream originalFile = uploadedFile.getInputstream();
    OutputStream fileOutput = null;

    try {
        fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("/pvtfiles/" + randomFilename);
        IOUtils.copy(originalFile, fileOutput);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileOutput);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(originalFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good question, but better if you provide some code about what are you doing right now ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating your own filter It will not create temp files. Please read my answer below on another post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19581257/185022

Comment: I think I understand what you are doing in your other answer, but I am having a hard time applying that to moving a large upload to am alternate location rather than deleting it. Can you expand on what should be put in the filter to accomplish this task?

Comment: I was able to figure out what to do and posted details in a separate answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do this by writing a custom filter, as AZ_ suggested, and adding the following:

```
FileItem fileItem = multipartRequest.getFileItem("form:fileUpload");
File file = new File(uploadDir + "/" + fileItem.getName());
fileItem.write(file);
```

The trick is to usethe `MultipartRequest` object to get the a `FileItem` object. `FileItem`'s 
`write` method can be used to save the file in a different location or using a different name. According to the documentation, some implementations may still do this with a copy, but what I am using (Apache Commons 1.3) seems to do this with a rename/move as desired. Note that the string used in `getFileItem` to find the `FileItem` is the ID attribute from the `<p:fileUpload>` tag.

More Code:

Modified portion of `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>some.package.CustomFileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Sample jsf:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" class="blockleft">
        <p:fileUpload
            id="fileUpload"
            auto="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Sample custom filter class:

```
package some.package;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.primefaces.webapp.MultipartRequest;
import org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class CustomFileUploadFilter extends FileUploadFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFileUploadFilter.class);

    private String thresholdSize;

    private String uploadDir;

    private final static String THRESHOLD_SIZE_PARAM = "thresholdSize";

    private final static String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PARAM = "uploadDirectory";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        thresholdSize = filterConfig.getInitParameter(THRESHOLD_SIZE_PARAM);
        uploadDir = filterConfig.getInitParameter(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PARAM);

        LOG.info("CatalogFileUploadFilter initiated successfully");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(httpServletRequest);

        if (isMultipart) {
            LOG.info("Parsing file upload request");

            DiskFileItemFactory diskFileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

            if (thresholdSize != null){
                diskFileItemFactory.setSizeThreshold(Integer.valueOf(thresholdSize).intValue());
            }
            if (uploadDir != null){
                diskFileItemFactory.setRepository(new File(uploadDir));
            }

            ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(diskFileItemFactory);
            MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(httpServletRequest, servletFileUpload);

            try {
                FileItem fileItem = multipartRequest.getFileItem("form:fileUpload");
                File file = new File("path/to/location/" + fileItem.getName());
                fileItem.write(file);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            LOG.info("File upload request parsed successfully, continuing with filter chain with a wrapped multipart request");

            filterChain.doFilter(multipartRequest, response);
        } else {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```